# Parameterizing a unitary transformation between pure states and viewing it as a rotation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, geometry, unitarity, quantum-states

Let $\vert\psi\rangle$ and $\vert\phi\rangle$ be pure states. Then there exists some unitary $U_t$ such that $U_t\vert\psi\rangle = \vert\phi\rangle$.

I have a geometric picture in my mind but I'm not sure if it is a valid one. Can one always imagine this unitary to be a paramterizable one i.e. $U = U(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is a rotation angle? $U(0)$ would then be $I$ while $U(\theta_t) = U_t$. In general, am I free to choose any other angle for $\theta$ and obtain a corresponding unitary that rotates along some plane in the Hilbert space? Is this "picture" of quantum states and rotations valid and if yes, I would be grateful for some links to where I can understand it better.

Comment: By pure states, do you mean eigenstates of some operator? Which operator: energy, angular momentum, other, or do you propose that it doesn't matter which operator?

Comment: @BillN it doesn't matter. Any rank-1 state can be chosen and there will always be a unitary connecting them. SolubleFish has answered it perfectly :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. First, you can always *choose* $U$ to be parametrizable. To see this, notice that you can choose an orthonormal basis $\{ |n\rangle\}$ such that $|0\rangle  = |\psi \rangle$ and $|\phi \rangle$ is a linear combination of $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$. You can then write :
   $$|\phi\rangle = e^{i\alpha}\cos\theta |0 \rangle + \sin\theta |1\rangle$$

With this, you can write down explicitly a unitary operator $U(t)$ such that $U(0) = \mathbf 1$ and $U(1) |\psi \rangle = |\phi\rangle$ :
$$U(t) = \begin{pmatrix}e^{it\alpha}\cos(t\theta) & - \sin (t\theta)\\
\sin(t\theta) &  e^{-it\alpha} \cos(t\theta)\\
& & 1\\
&&& \ddots \\
& & & & 1
 \end{pmatrix}$$

2. Then, a more abstract and more general argument : the group of unitary transformation of a Hilbert space is always path connected (when the Hilbert space is finite dimensional, this is basis matrix algebra, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_group#Topology) ; the infinite dimensional case, is *way* more involved). If you take $U_0$ and $U_1$ two unitary operators, you can always take a continuous family of operators $U(t)$ with $U(0) = U_0$ and $U(1) = U_1$

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you are confusing unitary transformations with rotations. Unitary means, assuming we are working in a complex Hilbert space with inner product $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$, that an operator $U:\mathcal{H}\rightarrow\mathcal{H}$ has the property $$U^\dagger U=U U^\dagger=I$$

Equivalently, being unitary means the inner product is preserved: $\langle U\psi,U \phi\rangle=\langle\psi,\phi\rangle$ for all vector in $\mathcal{H}$.
These operators form a group, namely $U(n)$, where $n$ is the dimension of the space we are working in.

Rotations are usually described by orthogonal operators, meaning $R^{T}R=RR^{T}=I$. Note that if we were dealing with a real Hilbert space, such as $\mathbb{R}^n$, orthogonal operators would also preserve the inner product

$$ \langle Ru,Rv\rangle = R R^{T} \langle u,v\rangle = \langle u,v\rangle$$
These operators also form a group, called the Orthogonal group $O(n)$, where $n$ is the, finite, dimension of the space. In fact, we may say that the Orthogonal group $O(n)$ is a *subgroup* of the Unitary group $U(n)$.

To answer your question: Yes, both these groups can be parametrized with a vector of real parameters **$\theta \in \mathbb{R}^n$**. However, the correct and rigorous geometrical interpretation of such groups is much more complicated when it comes to quantum mechanics. There are mainly two problems that need to be adressed: 1) we've implicitly assumed from the beginning that operators are bounded, which is not the case in quantum mechanics; 2) the dimension of quantum mechanical Hilbert space is not finite, even though it's assumed to be separable and therefore has a countable basis.

If you want to dig a little deeper I suggest looking at Lie Groups, Lie Algebras and representation theory in general. Links? There are lots of well done videos about representation theory, but I think I'd be better pairing them with a textbook. I strongly reccomend "Quantum Theory for Mathematicians" by Brian Hall. Rigorous and precise, it gives no physical explanation or insight, just pure math.