# Is that possible to have some state-specific unitary operator to escape from the non-clone theorem?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, unitarity

The [non-clone theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-cloning_theorem) states that for arbitrary states, it is not possible to have a unitary transformation such that
$$ 
\hat{U} |  \phi_A \rangle | e_B \rangle =  C | \phi_A \rangle | \phi_B \rangle
  $$
where $C$ is a phase factor. $A$ and $B$ are two general states.

In the proof in the above wiki link, the same unitary operator is applied to two general states $|\phi_A \rangle$ and $|\psi_A\rangle$.

My question is, is that possible to have some state-specific unitary operator to achieve the clone process? E.g., $\hat{U}_{\phi}^{-1} = \hat{U}^{\dagger}_{\phi}$ and $\hat{U}_{\psi}^{-1} = \hat{U}^{\dagger}_{\psi}$. Are there any results available in literature?

Comment: Could you make it clearer what you are asking : Are you asking if, for any fixed $|\phi\rangle,|e\rangle$, there is a unitary operator $U$ with $U|\phi\rangle_A |e\rangle_B = |\phi\rangle_A |\phi\rangle_B$ ?

Comment: I would say yes. (don't have to be as strong as *any* fixed)

Comment: [My answer there](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/634910) shows that given two states, you can find a unitary operator mapping one to the other.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's like the unitary rotation in spin 1/2 state in Sakurai's modern quantum mechanics!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The no-cloning theorem states that an *unknown* quantum state cannot be cloned. There is nothing preventing you to produce as many copies of a known quantum state as you wish.